# MVC3 @Context.User.Identity.Name empty value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

When User Presses Sign In button, following function in controller executes in which I set User's First name using `SetAuthCookie`:

```
// POST: /Account/SignUp
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ConsumerView consumerData)
    {
        try
        {
            ConsumerManager consumerManagerObj = new ConsumerManager();
            if (consumerManagerObj.IsValidUser(consumerData.LoginID, consumerData.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(consumerData.FirstName, false);
                return View ("WelcomeConsumer");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username/Password!!");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return View(consumerData);
        }

        return View(consumerData);
    }
```

`WelcomeConsumer` view have code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<h2>Welcome</h2>

<h2>Hi <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b></h2>
@Html.ActionLink("[Sign Out]", "SignOut", "ConsumerAccount")

<p>
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Book new Ticket", "NewBooking", "ConsumerAccount")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("View all Bookings", "ViewAllBookings", "ConsumerAccount")    </li>
</ul>
@ViewBag.NewBookingSuccess
</p>
```

But `@Context.User.Identity.Name` always have empty value in it. Any solution?

Comment: Which authorization you using?

Comment: I am new to MVC. Please explain

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx please check this

Comment: I added following lines in web.config but no success: <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/_ViewStart.chtml" />
   </authentication>

Answer (score 1):

User.Identity.Name is set in the `AuthenticateRequest` event which is far earlier than when your controller action is invoked. Calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` **ONLY** adds the authentication cookie to the response, it does not populate that value, which is why that is empty.

What you **would** see is that `User.Identity.Name` would be filled out on the next request to the page. Normally on a page that is doing authentication like this, you would redirect from the action that you are sending the `POST` request to the page that requires authentication.

Comment: Instead of `Return View(...);` you do a redirect: `Return RedirectToAction("Index");` It's a good practice to do a redirect after a successful (= data is valid, username/password are valid) POST. So that if the user refreshes the webpage he will not accidently do the post again.